# Autoescaping values from xml in Django templates

Tags: xml, django, django-templates

I use Django templates in order to store some XML strings.
The xml string looks like this:

```
<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.0.0"
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">
  <wfs:Update typeName="geonode:{{ layer_name }}">
   {% autoescape off %}{{ property_element }}{% endautoescape %}
   <ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:FeatureId fid="{{ layer_name }}.{{ feature_id }}"/>
  </ogc:Filter>
</wfs:Update>
```

As you can see I pass some variables such as property_element.
This variable is actually another xml string which looks like this:

```
property_element_1 = """<wfs:Property>
      <wfs:Name>{}</wfs:Name>
      <wfs:Value>{}</wfs:Value>
    </wfs:Property>\n""".format(attribute, value)
```

And this is how I render the attributes to my template:

```
xmlstr = get_template(xml_path).render(Context({
        'layer_name': layer_name,
        'coords': coords,
        'property_element': property_element})).strip()
```

The issue is that the part of xmlstr, which corresponds to

```
       property_element_1
```

doesn't get autoescaped. So I get values like: < and >

How can I autoescape them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your exact code? Asking because you are rendering a property element but you haven't defined one.

Anyway, the reason that the angular brackets are not being escaped is because:

```
{% autoescape off %}{{ property_element }}{% endautoescape %}
```

You've switched it off